# Dual Monitor Usage

Tags: display

I've got EOS v7.1 set up with 2 monitors.

The primary monitor is the right side one.

How do I switch that to the left side?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

There is a star in the upper left hand corner of the monitor in setup. That will change it.